# Removing rows by indexing

Tags: matlab

I have cell array of approx 300 rows. The array has 6 columns. In the 6th column very are lots of rows with zeros. I want to remove these rows from my array.

I am using the line below but getting an error message saying "Undefined function 'ne' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

```
myData = myData(myData(:,6) ~= 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a cell array of numerals, try this -

```
myData(~vertcat(myData{:,6}),6)={[]}
```

or

```
myData(~cell2mat(myData(:,6)),6)={[]}
```

or this, which is purely from @chappjc's comments

```
myData(~[myData{:,6}],6)={[]}
```

If it's a cell array of characters, try this -

```
myData(~str2double(myData(:,6)),6)={''}
```

**Edit 1:** If you would like to remove entire rows if the corresponding elements in the 6th column are zeros, index the whole row using `:`. Thus, the above codes would change to the following forms respectively :

```
myData(~vertcat(myData{:,6}),:)={[]}

myData(~cell2mat(myData(:,6)),:)={[]}

myData(~[myData{:,6}],:)={[]}

myData(~str2double(myData(:,6)),:)={''}
```

**Edit 2:** If you would like to remove the rows from the cell array that have all empty cells, you may use this -

```
myData(all(cellfun('isempty', myData),2),:) = []
```

Comment: The row index vector doesn't need to be a column, so you can even just do `horzcat` and simply test for inequality (`myData = myData([myData{:,6}]~=0,6);`). +1, but out of curiosity, why use `ismember`?

Comment: Well, I guess I have been obsessed with `ismember` lately! But yes that is redundant here. That `[]` works wonders with numeral cell arrays, thanks for that!!

Comment: these solutions do change the zero to [] but I was hoping the whole row would be removed. There are 6 rows the first two are text the remaining four are numeric, not sure if this makes a difference. I also guess I could copy the data to another matrix leaving the rows which have a zero in column 6 out

Comment: @mHelpMe Try this - `myData(~[myData{:,6}],:)={[]}`

Comment: @mHelpMe Check out **Edit 1** for the changes.

Comment: Ah of course I should have thought to change the 6 to :! Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @mHelpMe Check out **Edit 2** for some extra stuffs! Thought might come handy.